# woocommerce product gallery image spacing not

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Woocommerce site build with the Divi theme. I have issues with the spacing between the images in the product gallery. If there are 9 images shown on a page, then the spacing on the second and third row is not correct. Does anyone know how to resolve this?? thanks in advance!

regards,
Gerry
[product gallery woocommerce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV5xD.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide some html code or site link?

Comment: missing margin - some logic like item count/4

Comment: It's hard to tell without the code or a live link but it looks like it may be using the incorrect CSS  for the margin-right on the products of :nth-of-type(4n + 4) rather than :nth-of-type(3n + 3).

Comment: the link to the site is the following:  http://www.kendmedia.nl/speelgoedfeestje/product-categorie/buitenspeelgoed-tipi-speeltent-trampoline-makkelijk-bestellen/

Comment: I installed the WooCommerce Customizer plugin, altered some settings and this resolved my issues. Thanks for the replies all.